# Why does this js not working? Change onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Fast and probably easy for you problem to solve.

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("nav-icon3").attribute("onclick","closeNav()");
}
```

This function work fine with visibility and opacity but changing onclick function is not working. Any ideas?
Page: http://test.advermedia.pl/

Comment: Does your console shows any error?

Comment: Oh k....I just forgot to add setAttribute :D My bad sorry for problem haha

Comment: Adbur i did post page for you that you could watch all html tags and some of the css. This is whole js that you needed...So no im not promoting my site, im just learning...

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, specifically please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You have to set that attribute. Please try with the following:

```
document.getElementById("nav-icon3").setAttribute("onclick", "closeNav()");
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's `setAttribute()`, not `attribute()`. Secondly, that's pretty moot anyway as using  event attributes, let alone dynamically changing them at runtime, is a really bad idea. Use a single unobtrusive event handler instead:

```
<div id="nav-icon3">Toggle nav</div>
```

```js
document.getElementById("nav-icon3").addEventListener('click', function() {
  var nav = document.getElementById("myNav");
  nav.style.visibility = nav.style.visibility == 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
  nav.style.opacity = nav.style.opacity == '1' ? '0' : '1';
});
```

Or alternatively, as you've tagged jQuery:

```
$('#nav-icon3').click(function() {
  $('#myNav').toggle();
});
```